# unserialize data from mysql table and output via php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

My wp_usermeta table has 4 columns, umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
Image of table:
[image]

One of the columns has serialized data - wp_s2member_custom_fields.  How can I unserialize from mysql or output with php to see all of my users data within the serialized column?

Here is a breakdown of the serialized data:
wp_s2member_custom_fields

```
a:12:{
s:7:"country";
s:2:"CA";
s:4:"city";
s:8:"Brampton";
s:5:"state";
s:7:"Ontario";
s:8:"zip_code";
s:6:"L6T4E7";
s:3:"age";
s:13:"25–34 years";
s:8:"blog_url";
s:22:"http://www.blog.com";
s:16:"blog_description";
s:106:"A blog about blogging";
s:15:"monthly_uniques";
s:4:"1000";
s:13:"facebook_page";
s:55:"http://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage";
s:14:"facebook_likes";
s:3:"1428";
s:15:"twitter_account";
s:31:"http://twitter.com/mytwitterpage";
s:17:"twitter_followers";
s:3:"5849";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the data from the database and use PHP's `unserialize()`. There's no way of doing this in MySQL (or any other DB) and it's the main reason that most developers prefer to just write comma-separated valies in their tables.

Comment: How can you fetch the data and pull it into tables for all the data in the table?

Comment: That sentence doesn't make any sense, what do you mean?

Comment: In other words, how can I pull the serialized data into a html table?

Comment: `SELECT` it from the database, use `unserialize()` on the result to turn it into array and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress stores arrays/objects in the database by serializing them, so usually the retrieval function is what you want to look for since it will return the data unserialized.

In this case, it's **user_metadata**, so you need to use the function [get_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta%22get_user_meta%28%29%22), which you provide the $user_id and $key parameters to retrieve it.

In your example, it would be something like this:

```
<?php    
$array = get_user_meta(760, 'wp_s2member_custom_fields');
var_dump($array);
```

I hope that helps and makes sense...

**NOTE:**
The [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) is a priceless resource!

Comment: Awesome!  How about taking this and pulling all users into a table?